# How to retrieve total of "else if"

Tags: javascript, acrobat

How would I total these? If I add something like:

```
else if (cb1){ event.value[+=][1]this.getField("Totaldays").value*0;
}
```

It just extends the answer and doesn't give me the sum. For example:

[image]

```
else if (cb1){ event.value=this.getField("Totaldays").value*0;
}
else if (cb2){ event.value=this.getField("Totaldays").value*30; 
}
else if (cb3){ event.value=this.getField("Totaldays").value*20;
}
else if (cb4){ event.value=this.getField("Totaldays").value*0;
}
else if (cb5){ event.value=this.getField("Totaldays").value*40;
}
else if (cb6){ event.value=this.getField("Totaldays").value*0;
}
else if (c7){ event.value=this.getField("Totaldays").value*0;
}
```

Above is my current code which does not total the numbers, just replaces the previous number with the newly checked box number.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUvoM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simplified quite a bit. Understanding the way the return value of a checkbox works in Acrobat JavaScript is the key.

When the box is checked, it returns the specified value, when it is unchecked, it returns "Off". So, you can set the return value of the box to your rental fee. Also, assuming that the rental duration is the same for all items, the whole thing simplifies to:

```
var rentaldays = xx // xx is the number of days, not part of this snippet
var rsum = 0 ;
for (var i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++) {
rsum += this.getField("cb" + i).value.toString.replace(/Off/gim , 0)*1 ;
}
var rentalfee = rentaldays * rsum ; // to be written into a field
```

and that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `+=` operator instead of `+` to add a number to a running total.

```
//...
else if (cb1){ event.value += this.getField("Totaldays").value*0; }
else if (cb2){ event.value += this.getField("Totaldays").value*30; }
else if (cb3){ event.value += this.getField("Totaldays").value*20; }
else if (cb4){ event.value += this.getField("Totaldays").value*0; }
else if (cb5){ event.value += this.getField("Totaldays").value*40; }
else if (cb6){ event.value += this.getField("Totaldays").value*0; }
else if (cb7){ event.value += this.getField("Totaldays").value*0; }
```

That said, there's probably a better way to do what you want to do.  If you provide a little more context, I can refine my answer for you.

Consider this cleaner block of code that yields the same result as the code above but self-documents the logic and data.

```
let totalDays = this.getField("Totaldays").value;
[
    {checked: cb1, rentalRate:  0},
    {checked: cb2, rentalRate: 30},
    {checked: cb3, rentalRate: 20},
    {checked: cb4, rentalRate:  0},
    {checked: cb5, rentalRate: 40},
    {checked: cb6, rentalRate:  0},
    {checked: cb7, rentalRate:  0}
]
.filter(item => item.checked)
.forEach(item => {
    let rentalFee = item.rentalRate * totalDays;
    event.value += rentalFee;
});
```

Comment: I have 2 dates and a text box that determines the amount of days between dates. That being said above you can see that certain equipment has a rental fee. (cb2,cb3, and cb5). Currently I have it getting the total days of equipment use and multiplying it by the rental fee to give me a total cost for that piece of equipment. I am just trying to get it to add the equipment together in case someone wants to rent 2 pieces of equipment at the same time. For example is cb3 and cb5 were rented for 5 days, the total would read $300 total (200 for cb5 and 100 for cb3).

Comment: I added a picture above to show the rental page I am working with

Comment: OK. That makes sense.  Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Your code makes more sense and is much easier. Still playing with it as its throwing a "syntaxerror: missing ; before statement                                         
                                                                                                                          
   --------------------  let totalDays = this.getField("Totaldays").value;
     [    <= Right There
     {checked: cb1, rentalRate:  0}

Comment: Oops!  I forgot commas on my array! Updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: I'm going to show my entire code above, I wanna thank you for help so far on this! I am still playing with it, trying to get it to work as I am self taught and not very efficient. Haha

Comment: The code shown will not work in Acrobat JavaScript, because it is based on an older ECMA-262 version than Edition 6. The let operator will not be recognized. The error message you get when using the let operator is … you guessed it … "missing ; before statement"

Comment: @MaxWyss Interesting.  I suppose you could just `var` in that case.

Comment: That's correct. You may also look at other constructs which may not be understood.